# Computing Surface Integral over Tetrahedron

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

> Given a vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (2xz,0,(x-1)^2)$ and three points $P_1 = (1,0,0)$, $P_2 = (0,1,0)$, $P_3 = (0,0,2)$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Let $T$ be the tetrahedron with corners in $P_1, P_2, P_3$ and $(0,0,0)$, and let $\mathbf{\hat{N}}$ be the unit normal vector on the surface $\partial T$ pointing out of $T$.

> Compute $$\int \int_{\partial T} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{N}}dS.$$

My attempt: The plane passing through $P_1,P_2$ and $P_3$ is given by $2x + 2y + z = 2$. This gives $\mathbf{\hat{N}}dS = (2,2,1)dydx$, which further gives $\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{N}}dS = (-7x^2 + 6x - 8xy + 1) dydx$. By integrating over the projection of $T$ in the $xy$-plane, we obtain $$\int \int_{\partial T} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{N}}dS = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x}(-7x^2 + 6x - 8xy) dydx = \frac{7}{12}  .$$

However the correct answer is 1/3. Is anyone able to identify what I'm doing wrong? I'm aware that this can be solved using the divergence theorem, however I'm trying to compute the surface integral directly.

Comment: I think that's because you've computed the surface integral only over one surface of tetrahedron; compute the integral for the other faces and sum them up, then only will you obtain the correct value.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus I though the integrals over the other faces of the tetrahedron should cancel? So that only the bottom surface contributes since it doesen't have a counter part.

Comment: Should it, now? Is it always the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's because you've computed the surface integral only over one surface of tetrahedron; compute the integral for the other faces and sum them up, then we do obtain the correct value of $\frac{1}{3}$.

You have already computed the value of the integral for face $\ S_1$, which is $\frac{7}{12}$.

Now, observe that the given vector field **F** has no y-component, so we need not compute the integral of the face $\ S_3$ which has its unit normal along the $\ -j$ direction. It will be 0.

For the rest, we will have to compute the integrals. For $\ S_2$, whose normal is along $\ -k$:

**F** $\cdot \ n_2 \space dS  = -(x-1)^2 \ dx \ dy$

The bounds of the projection of the given tetrahedron onto the $\ xy$ plane will be $\ 0 <= x <= 1$ & $\ 0 <= y <= (1-x)$.

Computing the integral, we observe the value to be $ \frac{-1}{4}$.

Similarly, the surface $\ S_4$ whose normal is along $\ -i$:

**F** $\cdot \ n_4 \space dS  = -2xz \ dz \ dy$

The bounds of the projection of the given tetrahedron onto the $\ yz$ plane will be $\ 0 <= y <= 1$ & $\ 0 <= z <= 2(1-y)$.

Since $\ x = 0$ for $\ S_4$, the surface integral yet again becomes zero.

Thus, the required integral is $\frac{7}{12} + \frac{-1}{4} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Let me know if this solution clarifies your doubts.

Comment: I can see you got the right answer, but I'm still a bit confused. The faces in the $\pm i,j$ directions should cancel because they have opposite signs. That leaves only the bottom face which is what I thought I computed the surface integral for? If this is face $S_2$, then the correct answer should be given by the surface integral over $S_2$ only?

Comment: @Pame It's not that the vanishing contributions cancel each other, rather they are simply both zero due to the definition of $\mathbf F$ and the normal vector corresponding to either component surface in the planes $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: @user170231 But do you agree then that the only nonzero contribution is the one from the bottom surface/the surface in the $xy$-plane? Which is the one I calculated the contribution from myself, but obtained the wrong answer.

Comment: @Pame No, I agree with Scipio's assessment; you only integrated along one of the four component surfaces. How you got what you did is correct. Two of the faces contribute nothing, and we all agree that the integral over the slanted face is $7/12$. But none of this eclipses the contribution of the fourth face.